# why typescript typing syntax error for filter function

Tags: typescript

example is pretty basic but I still can't find the right syntax :

```
  let array = [1, 2, 3];
  array.filter(
  n: number => true
)
```

error message is : "cannot find name n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right syntax:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];

array.filter(
  (n: number) => true
)
```